# Flight booking with Philippine Airlines from LAS to MNL with connecting flights

Tags: connecting-flights

I have a booking with Philippine Airlines for a flight from LAS to MNL tomorrow, Feb. 17, 2019.  I have a connecting flights from LAS to LAX with American Airlines and LAX to MNL via Philippine Airlines.  May I know in which terminal I have to initially check in at McCarran Airport in Las Vegas for the first leg of my flight from LAS to LAX? Will it be at Terminal 1?

Answer (score 1):

American Airlines departs from [Terminal 1, D gates](https://www.mccarran.com/Terminals/T1) at McCarran. This information is on the airport web site.

If you are taking a taxi or Uber you can simply let them know you are going to Terminal 1, American Airlines.

After you check in with American, you will go through security and then take the Blue Line people mover to the D series gates. Be aware there are three separate security checkpoints in Terminal 1; you want to go through the one that is marked as leading to the D gates. If you don't see any sign, the check-in agent can point you in the right direction.